# PHP/Laravel 5.4 - Parsing a comma separated list to allow for same line OR multiple lines?

Tags: php, laravel, list, textarea, explode

I am creating a tool to send emails and I want to allow for the option to write them in one line separated by a comma and space:

```
test@email.com, test2@email.com
```

OR multiple lines separated by a comma and space (which inadvertently creates more space):

```
test@email.com,
test2@email.com
```

The php code for the first option is easy:

```
$addresses = explode(', ', $this->data['emails']);
```

Which creates an array like this when you multi-line it:

```
array:1 [
  0 => """
    test@email.com,\n
    test2@email.com
    """
]
```

Anyone know some simple logic/regex to allow for either? The first example of `$this->data['emails']` comes as a string:

```
"test@email.com, test2@email.com"
```

And the second has the special characters to account for:

```
"""
test@email.com, \n
test2@email.com
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, figured it out:

```
    if (strpos($this->data['emails'], "\n")) {
        $addresses = explode(", \n", $this->data['emails']);
    } else {
        $addresses = explode(',', $this->data['emails']);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$addresses = array_map('trim', explode(',', $this->data['emails']));
```